# I’m trying to charge a capacitor. Would a bridge rectifier charge it like a battery would?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics

Since a bridge rectifier converts ac to dc. Will this charge my capacitor to max capacity how hooking it up to a battery would? The positive is charging the anode, while the cathode is grounded. Any reason why this circuit would not work? When just trying to convert ac to do soley for the purpose of successfuly charging a capacitor.

[image: Rectifier circuit]

Comment: Yes, but this isn't a bridge rectifier.

Comment: If you are doing electricity experiments in your lab, you should really invest in a good lab power supply costing a couple hundred dollars at most. It will have adjustable voltage and current, built-in measurement of both, short circuit protection, galvanic isolation (like a transformer), and no possibility of touching dangerous voltages (they often go up to a maximum of 30V).

Comment: @J... I think it's clear the intention is to plug in the left side into a power supply (probably a wall outlet). Plugs are often drawn this way since the power supply isn't actually part of the circuit in question. Although usually the connections are labeled L/N

Comment: Once you've drawn the full wave rectifier correctly with the grounded centre tap on the transformer that looks like it's been deleted from the schematic, you'll find it's a low impedance voltage source, unsuited to capacitor charging, which is better done with a high impedance current source. Use a series impedance like a resistor, or a flyback converter which is inherently current output.

Answer (score 6):

The circuit you've shown does not work as you can see in this simulation:

https://tinyurl.com/y3dkokdy

Probably you are referring to the [single-way full-wave rectifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html) circuit or else known centre-tapped rectifier and not the more familiar double-way full-wave or else known [bridge rectifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html) in which however the use of [center-tapped transformer](https://engineering.electrical-equipment.org/electrical-distribution/centre-tapped-transformer.html) in the secondary winding is mandatory. The center tap connection in this case acts like the neutral thus the ground:

[image: single-way full-wave rectifier]

Here is a simulation of this circuit with the filter capacitor and a $1KΩ$ load:

https://tinyurl.com/y6zkwoyp

The transformer winding ratio is 1:1.

The $1:1$ windings ratio in transformers called also [isolation transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_transformer) *installed before the main appliance control fuse panel connection* is usually used for isolating the mains appliance from the [ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthing_system) so that a user accidentally touching a hot wire does not get electrocuted via the ground and without blowing any fuses at the mains control panel since there is no ground (Earth) connection back to the mains supply (**CAUTION!** does not offer protection when touching both hot and neutral wires in any installation or simultaneously different live hot wires L1 L2 L3 in a 3-phase installation).

[image: centre-tapped rectifier with filter and load simulation]

**Note:** Green waveform indicates voltage and yellow waveform current.

**CAUTION DANGER!!: THE CENTRE-TAPPED TRANSFORMER SHOWN ABOVE IN A $1:1$ CONFIGURATION CANNOT IN ANY CIRCUMSTANCES USED AS AN ISOLATION TRANSFORMER. DANGER OF ELECTROCUTION. ESPECIALLY FOR COUNTRIES WHICH ARE USING 240V MAINS ELECTRICITY. SEE BELOW FIGURE (STILL $120V$ ARE PRESENT!).**

[image: DANGER!]

Please read here:https://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/crosstalk-readers-writes

Comment: I've updated first simulation link. Simulation shows that the circuit is not working. Capacitor is not charging. Transformer ratio is set at 1:1.

Comment: Please, don't play with high power electricity. This can be very hazardous!

Comment: If it was a transformer without a center tap. How could I charge the capacitor with two diodes? I want full wave rectification without a center tap and only two diodes.

Comment: Answer was updated once more.

Comment: @TechMelts Please if you want to tackle with large power electricity 240/120V and if you are not experienced please stay out of it or hire a professional electrician.  At what kind of voltage level you like to charge the capacitor and what you mean you will connect the other end of the capacitor to the mains appliance ground?!!

Comment: @TechMelts Better play safe with lower input voltages. You can use a full wave voltage multiplier, see here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/voltage-multiplier-circuit.html and this tutorial video here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDQRB8DOJE4 .

Comment: @TechMelts, your choices are (in order of descending cost): 1. Get a transformer with a center-tapped secondary. 2. Buy two more diodes. 3. Use half-wave rectification.

Comment: @TechMelts The full wave voltage doubler uses a normal transformer and 2 diodes https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/voltage-multiplier-circuit.html , video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDQRB8DOJE4

Answer (score 5):

> Would this circuit charge the capacitor with the cathode to the ground outside?

No, there's no complete circuit by which current flows from the transformer secondary to the capacitor and back to the other terminal of the transformer secondary.

Comment: @TechMelts Please, don't play with high power electricity. This can be very hazardous.